# Connection is disconnected during Jenkins (Master-Slave structure)

Tags: java, jenkins

I'm currently having trouble running the system in the form of Jenkins Master Slave.

Some of the Master Server and Slave Server are built in the cloud, and the Cloud is built in Openstack.

Slave agent connection method is Launch agent via Java Web Start.

The problem is when working for a long time (about 15 hours or more?) between the master server and the slave server

My question is, I would like to know what is causing the network disconnection issue on the currently deployed system Jenkins (Master/Slave).

I'm curious about what is happening.

The corresponding error has occurred.

```
FATAL: command execution failed

java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.NetworkLayer.onRecvClosed(NetworkLayer.java:154)
at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.NIONetworkLayer.ready(NIONetworkLayer.java:179)
at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.IOHub$OnReady.run(IOHub.java:795)
at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Backing channel 'JNLP4-connect connection from vcdmpvbv04/{IP}:54142' is disconnected.
at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler.channelOrFail(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:214)
at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:283)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy68.isAlive(Unknown Source)
at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLauncher$ProcImpl.isAlive(Launcher.java:1150)
at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLauncher$ProcImpl.join(Launcher.java:1142)
at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.join(CommandInterpreter.java:155)
at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:109)
at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:66)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:741)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:206)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:163)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:504)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1818)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
FATAL: Unable to delete script file C:\Users\app****\AppData\Local\Temp\3\jenkins4846657243452131901.bat
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.NetworkLayer.onRecvClosed(NetworkLayer.java:154)
at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.NIONetworkLayer.ready(NIONetworkLayer.java:179)
at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.IOHub$OnReady.run(IOHub.java:795)
at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused: hudson.remoting.ChannelClosedException: Channel "unknown": Remote call on JNLP4-connect connection from vcdmpvbv04/{IP}:54142 failed. The channel is closing down or has closed down
at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:950)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1070)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1059)
at hudson.FilePath.delete(FilePath.java:1540)
at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:123)
at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:66)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:741)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:206)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:163)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:504)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1818)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure

Finished: FAILURE
```

Server performance is as follows.

CPU: Intel Xeon Skylake, 8-Core
RAM: 32G
DISK: C (100GB), NAS Drive Z (16TB)

Jenkins Version is 2.176.1.

The firewall was also suspected, so I tried removing all the firewalls, but nothing worked.

thanks

Comment: This questions seems more network related and might belong to a different platform than SO. And to answer the question, more information about the (virtual) network might be required.